# Can every real-analytic function be extended to one holomorphic outside a discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$? What about a meromorphic one?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Can every real-analytic function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
be extended to a holomorphic function $\tilde{f} : \mathbb{C}\setminus A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is some discrete subset, with $A \cap \mathbb{R} = \emptyset$?

If yes, what are the conditions on $f$ for $\tilde{f}$ to be furthermore meromorphic (i.e. such that the points where it is not defined are poles)?

More generally does it hold that every real-analytic function $\mathbb{R}\setminus A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is discrete,
can be extended to a complex function holomorphic except on a discrete subset? And what would be the conditions for meromorphicity?

Comment: Just fyi, that's not what a meromorphic function is. To be meromorphic, the singularities need to be removable or poles. If it has an essential singularity, then it is not meromorphic.

Comment: Are you interested in meromorphic functions, or in functions holomorphic outside discrete subset?

Comment: Ah I see, my mistake, I forgot to consider essential singularities. I will edit the question appropriately.

Comment: What about something like $\sqrt{1 + x^2}$?

Comment: A real-analytic function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ extends to an analytic function on some open set $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{R}$. However, there are plenty of examples where $\mathbb{C}\setminus U$ is large enough (and in particular, not discrete) for any maximal choices of $U$. User mihaild gave an example where the branch cuts are necessary, and user Jacob gave an example with lacunary behavior (i.e., where $U$ has a natural boundary beyond which $f$ cannot be extended).

Comment: Thank you for the comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

To begin, recall the standard example of an analytic function that cannot be extended to $\mathbb{C}$: $$\phi(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{z^{2^j}}$$  The standard proof of this notes that analytic functions cannot have accumulating poles, but $\phi$ has poles at every binary root of unity.

Now, $\phi$ is not real-analytic (although it has real coefficients), because it "blows up" outside $(-1,1)$.  But that difficulty is easy enough to fix: I claim $$z\mapsto\phi\left(\frac{\sin{z}}{2}\right)$$ is well-defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, analytic, and has maximal domain of extension that is much smaller than $\mathbb{C}$.

For analyticity, note $\sin$ is entire, and $\sin{0}=0$.  $\phi$ has a Taylor expansion at $0$, and so the power series compose term-by-term (even as formal series).  For maximal domain of extension, note that $$|\sin{\!(u+vi)}|=\sqrt{\frac{\cosh{\!(2v)}-\cos{2u}}{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your example!